# Update email column based on fullName in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose this table:

**Users**:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|FullName                               |Email                       |
|---------------------------------------|----------------------------|
|FirstName some MiddleNames LastName    |NULL                        |
|Washington L Guedes                    |NULL                        |
|...                                    |...                         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I update `Email` column:

```
firstname.lastname@specific.site
washington.guedes@specific.site
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to update Email column FirstName + dot + LastName + @specific.site? Excluding middle names?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas. Yes, But I don't know how to substring the fullname.

Comment: If you don't know how to substring then look at the syntax and examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen. But the length is arbitrary

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes check my answer, It should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

**QUERY TO SELECT**

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'FirstName some MiddleNames LastName '

SELECT SUBSTRING(@FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName) - 1) + '.' +
       REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@FullName), 1, 
               CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@FullName)) - 1) ) + '@specific.site' AS [Email]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Email
FirstName.LastName@specific.site
```

**QUERY TO UPDATE**

```
UPDATE Users
SET Email = SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) - 1) + '.' +
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(FullName), 1, 
                    CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName)) - 1) ) + '@specific.site'
```

**UPDATE #1**

As per your comment to remove spaces you have to use `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` and to get result in lowercase use `LOWER` in following:

```
update #t
set Email = LOWER(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(FullName)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(FullName))) - 1) + '.' +
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(FullName))), 1, 
                    CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(FullName)))) - 1) ) + '@specific.site')
```

Comment: It works !! .. Just to complete, is there a way to remove spaces after last name and before first name if exists, and to turn the email in lowercase? .. Thanks

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes updated my answer with query where removed spaces and result provided in lowercase. Now even if FullName will be provided with additional spaces It will return correct result.